# changing js variables which are parameters in a function?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to have multiple buttons use the same function. Here What I'm trying to do.

```
<button><a herf="#" onClick="myFunction('clk1',c1);">button</a></button>
<p id="clk1"></p>
```

With the buttons I want to change the variable and change the paragraph

```
<script>
    var c1 = 0;
    function myFunction(paragraph,varibl) {
            varibl += 1;
            document.getElementById(paragraph).innerHTML = varibl;
    }
</script>
```

I've looked around and can't find any thing. this doesn't work and I don't know how to make it work.

the full code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<head>
    <title>clicker clicker</title>
    <style>
        html {
            text-align: center;
            background-color: #d1d1d1;
            font-family:Verdana;
        }
        .onebutton {
        background-color: #f4f4f4;
        border: 2px solid #5b5b5b;
        color: #5b5b5b;
        text-align: center;
        text-decoration: none;
        display: inline-block;
        font-size: 32px;
        cursor: pointer;
        border-radius: 8px;
        box-shadow:inset 0px 12px 22px 2px #ffffff;
        }
        .onebutton:active {
            background-color: #e5e5e5;
        }
        .twobutton {
        background-color: #f4f4f4;
        border: 2px solid #5b5b5b;
        color: #5b5b5b;
        text-align: center;
        text-decoration: none;
        display: inline-block;
        font-size: 16px;
        cursor: pointer;
        border-radius: 8px;
        box-shadow:inset 0px 12px 22px 2px #ffffff;
        }
        .twobutton:active {
            background-color: #e5e5e5;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Clicker Clicker</h1>
    <p id="number"></p>
    <button class="onebutton"><a herf="#" onClick="clc();">click</a>
</button>
    <br>
    <p>clicker:100</p>
    <button class="twobutton"><a herf="#" 
onClick="upgrade('clk1',c1);">buy</a></button>
    <p id="clk1"></p>
    <p>clicker:1000</p>
    <button class="twobutton"><a herf="#" onClick="upgrade('clk2',c2);">buy</a></button>
    <p id="clk2"></p>
    <script>
        var number = 0;
        var c1 = 0;
        var c2 = 0;
        document.getElementById("number").innerHTML = number;

        function clc() {
            number += 1;
            document.getElementById("number").innerHTML = number;
        }
        function update() {
            number += c1;
            document.getElementById("number").innerHTML = number;
            c1 += c2;
            document.getElementById("clk1").innerHTML = c1;
        }
        function upgrade(what,clicker) {
            window[clicker] += 1;
            document.getElementById(what).innerHTML = clicker;
        }   
        setInterval(update, 100);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

this is here so it doesnt say i have to much code sdljnvaksjdnfblkajsdbfjmas dbfmha bsdmnfb admsf bds msadf

Comment: What seems to be not working ?

Comment: the variable dosn't change when the button is pressed

Comment: Check the below answer, I updated the example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***User can use object for easy modification of values inside function***

```
<button><a herf="#" onClick="myFunction('clk1','c1');">button</a></button>
<p id="clk1"></p> 
..
<button><a herf="#" onClick="myFunction('clk1','c2');">button</a></button>
<p id="clk1"></p> 
..
<button><a herf="#" onClick="myFunction('clk1','c3');">button</a></button>
<p id="clk1"></p>
```

and the script

```
<script>
    var c = {c1: 0, c2: 0, c3: 0}
    function myFunction(paragraph,varibl) {
            c[varibl] = c[varibl] + 1 
            document.getElementById(paragraph).innerHTML = c[varibl];
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

do this:

```
<button><a herf="#" onClick="myFunction('clk1');">button</a></button>
<p id="clk1"></p>
```

and then:

```
<script>
    var c1 = 0;
    function myFunction(paragraph) {
            c1++;
            document.getElementById(paragraph).innerHTML = c1;
    }
</script>
```

each time you call this method, the variable goes up by one!
[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vqrz4ado)

Comment: thank you but i want to have more buttons with c1, c2, c3... variables

Comment: take a look at jsfiddle! isn't this what you want? i edited the post.

Comment: @jnick in that case you might want to use my example and just add more keys to your counter.

Answer (score 1):

If you have to pass the variable using the signature and can't simply (as per the other answers) directly reference the correct one in the function, here's what you do.

JS **always** passes a variable by value, not reference. However, if you send an object, the "value" is actually a reference to the original object. So you can do something like this:

```js
var counters = { a: 0 };
function test(key) {
  counters[key]++;
  console.log(counters);
}
```

```html
<button onclick="test('a')">Click</button>
```

Comment: this actually works, but this is really unnecessary coding. don't you agree?

Comment: True. But I don't usually assume we have the full context in SO questions - OP might have needed to use it this way for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<body>
<button><a herf="#" onClick="myFunction('clk1','c1');">Para 1</a></button>
<p id="clk1"></p>

<button><a herf="#" onClick="myFunction('clk2','c2');">Para 2</a></button>
<p id="clk2"></p>

<button><a herf="#" onClick="myFunction('clk3','c3');">Para 3</a></button>
<p id="clk3"></p>

<script>
    var c = {c1:0, c2:0, c3:0};
    function myFunction(paragraph,varibl) {
            document.getElementById(paragraph).innerHTML = ++c[varibl];
    }
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: this doesn't do

Comment: @Moher what doesn't do, it seems to be changing the value.

Comment: i doesn't increment value for me though